# How to add git submodule with nested submodules?

Tags: git

How to add a submodule with nested submodules?

When I do the following only the root submodule is added. How to add all submodules in the submodule recursively?

```
git submodule add https://the-submodule.git path/to/submodule
```

In the above submodule there is a nested submodule and the folder is not even created after cloning

```
path/to/submodule                   <- root submodule
path/to/submodule/nested-submodule  <- nested submodule (folder not even created)
```

The main project is on github and the submodule is gitlab (with including nested submodules)

Comment: Use submodules with caution. It is a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After cloning you have to init recursively with

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This will do what you want